# Como arreglar unexpected unindent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

este es el error que aparece, en python, no se a que se debe.

```
  File "app.py", line 48
Button(root, text="1", command=lambda:get_numbers(1)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W+E)
^
```

IndentationError: unexpected unindent

esta es la linea de codigo que aparece que esta mal

```
Button(root, text="1", command=lambda:get_numbers(1)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W+E)
```

Alguien podría ayudarme con la solución? Ya me ha pasado en otros proyectos y no se a que se debe.

El error me cambio de posicion, aqui dejo la parte de codigo.

```
def calculate():
display_state = display.get()
    try:
        math_expression = parser.expr(display_state).compile
        result = eval(math_expression)
        clear_display()
        display.insert(0, result)
    except:
        clear_display()
        display.insert(0, "error")  

def get_numbers(n):
    global i
    display.insert(i, n)
    i+=1

def get_operation(operator):
    global i
    operator_length = len(operator)
    display.insert(i,operator)
    i+=operator_length
```

el error me aparece en def get_numbers(n):.
Debería incluir todo el código? 
He tratado de quitar el comando except, ya que al ponerlo me da 100 advertencias, al quitarlo me da error y no funciona el programa.

Comment: ¿Puedes intentar colocar un poco más del bloque de código para poder ver mejor el error? Ya que con tan sólo ver la línea del error no se puede visualizar el porqué te dice "IndentationError: unexpected unindent"

Comment: En este caso sería conveniente que adjuntases el código o una mayor parte del código para poder ver dónde se encuentra el error de identación. Si adjuntas una linea de código siempre va a estar bien identada. Gracias!

Comment: Wiljunior, el error es el mismo, creo que antes de seguir deberías comprender como funciona la identación en Python. El sangrado junto a `:` determina los bloques de código. El sangrado comienza un bloque y su ausencia lo termina. No hay llaves, corchetes ni palabras clave (BEGIN/END) explícitas como en C++, Java, etc.  La línea `display_state = display.get()` si es parte de la función tiene que estar identada un nivel más que la definición de la función, tiene que quedar a la misma altura que el `try` porque pertenece al mismo bloque de código.

Comment: La función `def calculate():` termina cuando se **encuentra otra línea a su mismo nivel de sangría**, que en tu caso es `display_state = display.get()`, que es tu error, porque debe ser `def get_numbers(n):`. Es una decisión de diseño, primero porque se evita el uso de llaves o elementos accesorios para delimitar los bloques lo cual ayuda a la "limpieza" y simplicidad del código, pero sobretodo porque obliga a identar/sangrar el código correctamente y eso es siempre una idea excelente se esté usando el lenguaje que se esté usando, porque facilita enormemente la legibilidad del código.

Comment: Por cierto, `try-except` (manejo de excepciones) es una prácticas bien vistas generalmente y usada en Python, pero jamás debe usarse para enmascarar errores que no sabemos de dónde vienen (por si acaso funciona...), se usa siempre para manejar excepciones que sabemos **exactamente cuándo y porqué** se van a producir. Nunca debe usarse `except:` sino manejar el error o errores concretos de turno, `except ValueError:`, `except (ValuError, MathError):`, etc. No se los avisos que te genera, pero muy posiblemente el linter de tu IDE no vea lo comentado con buenos ojos :)

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla

Comment: Si estás en Visual Studio Code, puede presionar las siguientes teclas para que te agregue los tabulados correctamente "Alt + Shift + F"

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el propio error, es un error de **identación**. Este error se produce al no tener la identación de forma correcta en tú código.

### ¿Qué es la identación?

Es la separación de espacios que existe desde el margen izquierdo, hasta la primera letra de tu código. En este caso **Python funciona mediante tabulaciones**

### ¿Cuando suele surgir este error?

1. Cuando no se tabulan correctamente, bucles, funciones, clases, etc.
2. Hay una tabulación (son 4 espacios) que le falta un espacio, o le sobra un espacio (es decir que tiene 3 o 5 espacios). A veces es difícil de visibilizar.

**Nota**

En ocasiones la linea en la que marca el error, no corresponde con la que tiene el error en realidad, y puede estar en la anterior o siguiente identación mal hecha.